# Google autocomplete list limit by country

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

i need your help for a little thing with the autocomplete list from google API.

I have a new installation of wordpress and my theme use this method to select an address but i want to limit the list for only one country, this is my jQuery code :

```
    jQuery("#address").autocomplete({

                                      //This bit uses the geocoder to fetch address values

                                      source: function(request, response) {

                                        geocoder.geocode( {'address': request.term }, function(results, status) {

                                          response(jQuery.map(results, function(item) {

                                            return {

                                              label:  item.formatted_address,

                                              value: item.formatted_address,

                                              latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),

                                              longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()

                                            }

                                          }));

                                        })

                                      },
```

How can i do that?

Comment: ok, i've found ! For the people who need to do this too just add this :  'address': request.term,
'componentRestrictions':{'country':'IT'} //any country code...